# I can´t connect with phpseclib

Tags: php, phpseclib

I have this code in a simple way to connect SFTP and upload files for a CMR, until php 7.4 everything works, now with PHP 8.0 or superior, it´s useless.

I have this code below:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . './phpseclib0.3.0');

if(!include('Net/SSH2.php')){
    echo "ssh2 not included<br>";
}else{}
if(!include('Net/SFTP.php')){
    echo "sftp not included";
}else{}

$strServer = 'mi hoting';
$intPort = 22;
$strUsername = 'my user';
$strPassword = 'my pass';

$objFtp = new Net_SFTP($strServer, $intPort);

if (!$objFtp ->login($strUsername, $strPassword)) {
    exit( 'Login Failed' );
}
$objFtp->disconnect();
```

Someone knows or see my mistake
The phpseclib0.3.0 folder it´s in the same directory as the ftp connection file

Comment: What is not working as intended, did your page throw an exception ?

Comment: The sftp connection it´s not working at all, now I see maybe the phpseclib directory it´s not working well, bacause chow me redunderline in the functions like Net_SFTP, but when I test the include say YES.

Comment: PHPSecLib v0.3.0 is over 10 years old and was made for PHP v5. You can't expect it to still work with PHP v8.

Comment: Use phpseclib 1.0.21. The API is basically the same as 0.3.0 and it's also not 10yo like Alex Howansky pointed out.